# Auth Callback with Mechanize

Tags: ruby, ajax, mechanize, web-crawler

I've been getting some great answers so far about Mechanize, so thanks StackOverflow!

Here's another:

I've been using Mechanize even for Ajax-based logins, and it's been working well for me so far. Now, I've encountered one scenario that is a little confusing.

When I hit the login button, there is a GET request to a callback url as follows:

```
https://www.gilt.com/login/auth?callback=jQuery1720030715713743120432_1360278619610&email=username%40gmail.com&password=password&remember_me=on&_=1360278631042
```

What do the following query terms mean?

```
callback=jQuery1720030715713743120432_1360278619610
```

and

```
_=1360278631042
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a jquery version number and a timestamp. Probably nothing you should care about.

Comment: Cool - just wondering if it impacted my Mechanize login, since it changes everytime. Seems like it doesn't matter though. Thanks!